# Flask - Unable to register a before filter inside an application factory

Tags: python, flask

In Flask, I can only create a before filter inside of my application factory if I use `@app.before_request` and include all the code for the before filter **inside the application factory**.

When I move the logic into a function (`register_before_request`) and call that function from the application factory, it breaks the styling of all pages and throws an error into the JS console.

Here is the code that works:

```
def create_app(config_object=ProdConfig):
    """
    An application factory, as explained here:
    http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/appfactories/
    """

    app = Flask(__name__.split('.')[0])
    app.config.from_object(config_object)

    @app.before_request # <------------------------- this works
    def make_before_request():
        if current_user.is_authenticated and not current_user.status and request.endpoint not in ['main.unconfirmed']:
        return redirect(url_for('main.unconfirmed'))
    ...

    return app
```

But, I want to defer registering the before filter to a **separate function** called from within my application factory (passing the instance of `app` with it):

```
def create_app(config_object=ProdConfig):
    """
    An application factory, as explained here:
    http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/appfactories/
    """

    app = Flask(__name__.split('.')[0])
    app.config.from_object(config_object)
    register_before_request(app) # <------------------------- this doesn't work
    ...

    return app

def register_before_request(app):
    """Register before request actions."""

    def make_before_request():
        if current_user.is_authenticated and not current_user.status and request.endpoint not in ['main.unconfirmed']:
            return redirect(url_for('main.unconfirmed'))

    app.before_request(make_before_request)
```

For some reason, this causes **any** page (not just `main.unconfirmed`) to render completely unstyled and with this error in the JavaScript console and about 6-7 redirects to the same page:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`

The unexpected token it's referencing is the `<html>` tag (the start of the web page).

Here's the route:

```
@blueprint.route('/unconfirmed/', methods=['GET'])
def unconfirmed():
    return render_template('main/main_unconfirmed.html')
```

Why does this happen? I use this same pattern to register extensions, blueprints, and other things and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be that you can't pass a function to `app.before_request`.

So, this appears to be never possible:

`app.before_request(<function>)`

Instead, `@app.before_request` has to be used as a decorator but we can decorate the inner function that gets called from the main application factory.

Solution:

```
def register_before_request(app):
    """Register before request actions."""

    @app.before_request # <--------- must use this decorator here
    def make_before_request():
        if current_user.is_authenticated and not current_user.status and request.endpoint not in ['main.unconfirmed']:
            return redirect(url_for('main.unconfirmed'))
```